# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, alarmmanager

I was beginer in codes. i've try to make android reminder app. i am using firebase realtime database to store datas, and i retrieve the datas to my app to set reminder using AlarmManager, and it's work to reminding on alert and notification. but after i open notification from my phone the app was crash. anyone can help me to replace my wrong code with work code ? thankyou

**XML (activity_detail.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity">



        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="==================DETAIL_ACARA==================="
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/namaDetailTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="RAPAT ANGGOTA"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                        android:textColor="#ff6c22"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tanggalLabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="#646262"
                            android:text="TANGGAL : "
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tanggalDetailTextView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="#646262"
                            android:text="11 Januari 2019"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/waktuLabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="#646262"
                            android:text="WAKTU : "
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/waktuDetailTextView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="#646262"
                            android:text="18:00"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/wibLabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="#646262"
                            android:text="WIB"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tempatLabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="#646262"
                            android:text="TEMPAT : "
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tempatDetailTextView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="#646262"
                            android:text="Student Lounge"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/batas1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="====================DESKRIPSI====================="
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/deskripsiDetailTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#646262"
                    android:maxLines="20"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Jelasno jall"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/batas2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="=================================================="
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/alarmToggle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Alarm On/Off"
                    android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
                    android:textOn="Matikan Pengingat"
                    android:textOff="Ingatkan Saya"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA (MainActivity.java)**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import id.restabayu.clientsatu.Lainlain.Help;
import id.restabayu.clientsatu.Lainlain.Pengurus;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**********************************FIREBASE HELPER START************************/
    public class FirebaseHelper {

        DatabaseReference db;
        ArrayList<Classified> classifieds = new ArrayList<>();
        ListView mListView;
        Context c;
        ProgressBar progressBar;


        /*
       let's receive a reference to our FirebaseDatabase
       */
        public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db, Context context, ListView mListView) {
            this.db = db;
            this.c = context;
            this.mListView = mListView;
            this.retrieve();
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }


        /*
        Retrieve and Return them clean data in an arraylist so that they just bind it to ListView.
         */
        public ArrayList<Classified> retrieve() {
            db.child("classified").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    classifieds.clear();
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            //Now get Classified Objects and populate our arraylist.
                            Classified classified = ds.getValue(Classified.class);
                            classifieds.add(classified);
                        }
                        adapter = new CustomAdapter(c, classifieds);
                        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(classifieds.size());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d("mTAG", databaseError.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(c, "ERROR " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            return classifieds;
        }

    }

    /**********************************CUSTOM ADAPTER START************************/
    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context c;
        ArrayList<Classified> classifieds;

        public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Classified> classifieds) {
            this.c = c;
            this.classifieds = classifieds;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return classifieds.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return classifieds.get(getCount() - position - 1);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model, parent, false);
            }

            TextView nameTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            TextView quoteTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.quoteTextView);
            TextView descriptionTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);

            final Classified s = (Classified) this.getItem(position);

            nameTextView.setText(s.getNama());
            quoteTextView.setText(s.getDeskripsi());
            descriptionTextView.setText(s.getTanggal());

            //Saat Acara Di Tap Maka akan membuka detailActivity
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String[] classifieds = {
                            s.getNama(),
                            s.getTanggal(),
                            s.getWaktu(),
                            s.getTempat(),
                            s.getDeskripsi(),
                    };
                    openDetailActivity(classifieds);
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }


        private void openDetailActivity(String[] data)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("NAMA_KEY",data[0]);
            i.putExtra("TANGGAL_KEY",data[1]);
            i.putExtra("WAKTU_KEY",data[2]);
            i.putExtra("TEMPAT_KEY",data[3]);
            i.putExtra("DESKRIPSI_KEY",data[4]);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    /**********************************TOOLBAR MENU*************************************/
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            //nyoboo
            case R.id.menuPengurus:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Pengurus.class));
                break;

            case R.id.menuHelp:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Help.class));
                break;

            case R.id.menuLogout:
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogLogout)
                        .setTitle("Yakin Ingin Logout ?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Goodbye.class));
                            }

                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Tidak", null)
                        .show();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /************************************EXIT DIALOG************************************/
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogStyle)
                .setTitle("Apakah anda yakin ingin keluar ?")
                .setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("Tidak", null)
                .show();
    }


    /**********************************MAIN ACTIVITY CONTINUATION************************/
    //instance fields
    DatabaseReference db;
    FirebaseHelper helper;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    ListView mListView;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //nyobo
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");


        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        //initialize firebase database
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        helper = new FirebaseHelper(db, this, mListView);
        }
    }
```

**JAVA (DetailActivity.java)**

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.lang.String;

import id.restabayu.clientsatu.Service.AlarmReciever;
import id.restabayu.clientsatu.Service.Converter;
import id.restabayu.clientsatu.Service.AlarmService;



public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView namaTxt,tanggalTxt,waktuTxt,tempatTxt,deskripsiTxt;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        namaTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namaDetailTextView);
        tanggalTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tanggalDetailTextView);
        waktuTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.waktuDetailTextView);
        tempatTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempatDetailTextView);
        deskripsiTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deskripsiDetailTextView);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        ToggleButton alarmToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.alarmToggle);

        //GET INTENT
        Intent i = this.getIntent();

        //RECEIVE DATA
        String nama = i.getExtras().getString("NAMA_KEY");
        String tanggal = i.getExtras().getString("TANGGAL_KEY");
        String waktu = i.getExtras().getString("WAKTU_KEY");
        String tempat = i.getExtras().getString("TEMPAT_KEY");
        String deskripsi = i.getExtras().getString("DESKRIPSI_KEY");


        //BIND DATA
        namaTxt.setText(nama);
        tanggalTxt.setText(tanggal);
        waktuTxt.setText(waktu);
        tempatTxt.setText(tempat);
        deskripsiTxt.setText(deskripsi);


    }



        public void onToggleClicked (View view) {
            String date = Converter.ConvertDate(tanggalTxt.getText().toString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy MM dd");
            String time = waktuTxt.getText().toString();
            String dateTime = date + " " + time;
            Date txtAlarm = Converter.toDate(dateTime, "yyyy MM dd HH:mm");
            if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
                Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm On");
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(txtAlarm);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(DetailActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            }

            else {
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm Off");
            }
        }
}
```

**JAVA (AlarmService.java)**

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

import id.restabayu.clientsatu.DetailActivity;
import id.restabayu.clientsatu.R;

public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

    private NotificationManager alarmNotificationManager;

    public AlarmService() {
        super("AlarmService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //sendNotification("Tangi gan!");
        showNotification("PENGINGAT !", "Acara Segera Dimulai ! Silahkan Mempersiapkan Diri");
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        Log.d("AlarmService", "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Notif Show", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setContentTitle("Alarm").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);


        alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
        Log.d("AlarmService", "Notification sent.");
    }

    private void showNotification(String title, String body) {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class), 0);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "id.restabayu.clientsatu.test";

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,"Notification",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("IK Channel");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,1000});
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentInfo("info")
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

**Logcat**

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at id.restabayu.clientsatu.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:52)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try to include only relevant code snippets in order to track down your issue.

Comment: highlight headings

Answer (score 0):

Replace this `

```
    Intent i = this.getIntent();

    //RECEIVE DATA
    String nama = i.getExtras().getString("NAMA_KEY");
    String tanggal = i.getExtras().getString("TANGGAL_KEY");
    String waktu = i.getExtras().getString("WAKTU_KEY");
    String tempat = i.getExtras().getString("TEMPAT_KEY");
    String deskripsi = i.getExtras().getString("DESKRIPSI_KEY");
```

`
with

```
  Intent i = this.getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        String nama = b.getString("NAMA_KEY", "none");
        String tanggal = b.getString("TANGGAL_KEY", "none");
        String waktu = b.getString("WAKTU_KEY", "none");
        String tempat = b.getString("TEMPAT_KEY", "none");
        String deskripsi = b.getString("DESKRIPSI_KEY", "none");
    }
```

in DetailActivity

Answer (score 0):

You send some data from MainActivity.java to DetailActivity.java and it work good as i see but when you open `DetailActivity` from notification you don't send that data and this cause the error . You must send data(classifieds) from  AlarmService to DetailsActivity like MainActivity

**1)** Change in `AlarmService.java` `showNotification()` functions like this

```
String[] datas = {Your_DATA1,Your_DATA2}; // replace and send your data from here 
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                getIntentt(datas), 0);
```

And create `getIntentt` function

```
private Intent getIntentt(String[] data) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("NAMA_KEY",data[0]);
        i.putExtra("TANGGAL_KEY",data[1]);
        i.putExtra("WAKTU_KEY",data[2]);
        i.putExtra("TEMPAT_KEY",data[3]);
        i.putExtra("DESKRIPSI_KEY",data[4]);
        return i;
    }
```

You use one extra comma, remove that for feature bug

```
 String[] classifieds = {
                        s.getNama(),
                        s.getTanggal(),
                        s.getWaktu(),
                        s.getTempat(),
                        s.getDeskripsi(), // here this comma , REMOVE it
                };
```

Comment: thankyou, i was removed extra comma. but still error sir

Comment: not yet sir, i was import class named Classified to AlarmService class. and i define "public  Classified cl ;" in AlarmService Clas. then i put "String[] datas = {cl.getNama(), cl.getTanggal(), cl.getWaktu(), cl.getTempat(), cl.getDeskripsi(), cl.getNotif()};" like your suggestion. but my app was crash when alarm ringing and notification does'nt show. do you can help me if i give you the link of my project sir? thankyou very much